# Why do I get AttributeError: module 'google_cloud_pipeline_components.aiplatform' has no attribute 'EndpointDeleteOp' in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

My code is:

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform
from google_cloud_pipeline_components import aiplatform as gcc_aip
... (in a pipeline definition:)
 delete_endpoint_op = gcc_aip.EndpointDeleteOp(some_condition)
```

and when I compile the pipeline I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'google_cloud_pipeline_components.aiplatform' has no attribute 'EndpointDeleteOp'
```

but [this](https://google-cloud-pipeline-components.readthedocs.io/en/google-cloud-pipeline-components-1.0.0/google_cloud_pipeline_components.aiplatform.html#google_cloud_pipeline_components.aiplatform.EndpointDeleteOp) says it exists. Could this be I am importing the wrong version, and, if so, how do I check and fix? TIA!

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is a version issue, check the version:

```
!python3 -c "import google_cloud_pipeline_components; print('google_cloud_pipeline_components version: {}'.format(google_cloud_pipeline_components.__version__))"
```

update it:

```
!pip3 install google-cloud-pipeline-components --upgrade
```